# Anime where they summon monsters using crystal balls attached into their body parts

Tags: story-identification, anime

I need help identifying this anime where the lead character is a white haired guy and he's got crystal balls attached into his left arm which enables him to summon monsters. I remember one of his monsters is a green humanoid ladylike monster.

One of his friends is a girl with the crystal balls on her chest and her monster is a humanoid lady + jellyfish or something.

I think it was aired around early 2010's... I'm not sure.

Comment: Hey there! That's a nice start but could yu please take a look at [these guidelines on story-id](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028) and [these nes on anime](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/98028), see if that triggers any more memories you could [edit] in?

Comment: Ehm, but now you guys have closed the older one as a duplicate of this new one. Strange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[*Kiba*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kVxc7lhKjW4), which aired in 2006-2007?

From [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/anime/845/Kiba):

> In a dystopian future, two friends dream of freedom... and gain more than they bargain for! Hothead Zed is on the run from the authorities, while his brainy pal Noah struggles with his own battered body. Both find a magical world that seems to offer escape and power undreamed of. Join Zed and his powerful, rebellious spirit Amir Gaul on their search for the ultimate power. It's a force that can save the world—or destroy life as we know it. This is the world of KIBA! Where you must harness the power within and fight with all you got!

Here's the lead character, Zed. White-haired, has three "shards" on his arm:

[image: Zed, white-haired guy with crystals on his arm]

And here is Roya, who wears a crystal on her chest, and her spirit Afkareru, who does look a bit like a jellyfish:

[image: Roya and Afkareru]

---

I found it by searching this site for `[story-identification] anime arm is:q` which returned, among others, [Anime with character who has markings/balls on his arm that allow him to operate weapons](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/190007)

Comment: Yes that's the one! Thank you so much <3

Comment: I've been searching for that anime for years lol and I remember now that it was aired on the local channel in my country like 10yrs ago... Really takes me back